# Why is pessimistic locking not working for me in psql? The code is not concurrent as I would expect it to be

Tags: go, concurrency, transactions, psql, isolation-level

I am trying to get and update a column and need this process to be concurrent. Therefore, I do a row level lock via `SELECT FOR UPDATE`and then do my calculations and then do my update, all within a transaction with isolation level `repeatable read`.However, this is still not concurrent as expected. This column is just a random column and not the primary or a foreign key.

I changed this to optimistic locking after and that worked but I am trying to understand why this did not work. I ran this code below concurrently multiple times and it did not behave the same way as it would have if I individually ran it the same number of times.

```
_, err = s.xStore.ManageTransaction(func(ctx context.Context, tx *sqlx.Tx) (interface{}, error) {
                _, err := tx.Exec("set transaction isolation level repeatable read")
                if err != nil {
                    return nil, err
                }
                c, err = s.xStore.GetForUpdate(x) 
                //Some calculations
                _ = s.xStore.Update(c)
                return nil, nil
            })
            return
    }()
}
```

Here is my Get query with a FOR UPDATE to lock the row.

```
func (s *xStore) GetForUpdate(id string) (*model.X, error) {
    query := `
        SELECT * FROM things where id = $1 FOR UPDATE`

    _, err := s.db.Exec(query, id)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var x model.X
    err := s.db.Get(&x, query, id)
    err = s.db.Get(&x, query, id)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &x, nil
}
```

Comment: Explain what you mean by "not concurrent as expected". What did you expect? What did it do?

Comment: My bad! I mean that running the code concurrently multiple times did not produce the same result as running it individually multiple times. There were race conditions as the SELECT retrieved the same value in different threads and therefore updated to the same value.

Comment: Repeatable read allow serialization anomalies: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html

Comment: It doesn't look like you are using the same transaction. You don't pass `tx` to either `GetForUpdate` or `Update`.

Comment: @BurakSerdar serializable does not work either. Still not concurrent.

Comment: @RichardHuxton would it be possible for you to provide an example where tx is passed in golang? I am not sure how to do that?

Comment: Not a go expert, but I think you normally just use the Tx object in place of the Db object for Query/Exec etc.

Comment: @RichardHuxton, that worked! I really appreciate it! I spent a week on this haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is executing queries in different transactions ,
create new one (db.BeginTx) or use provided someway like :

- rows := tx.Query( *your query* )
- do some calc
- tx.ExecContext
- tx.Commit

(Referring to  https://go.dev/doc/database/execute-transactions )